# Best way to change states in a 'menu' UserControl in WPF

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have a UserControl which I want to have 3 possible states:

```
-Main menu
-Config #1
-Config #2
```

(All three are UserControls with various buttons, textboxes, etc., and the parent UserControl's states set the child controls to visible/not visible depending on the current state.)

The main menu state has buttons to go to either of the 2 config states (and both of those states have a 'back' button to return to the main menu).

What is the 'easiest' way to implement this workflow?  Do I need to do view changes manually and implement a click handler for each button, changing the state of the parent component?  (I'm doing this in Blend so I'm trying to avoid having to write C# code outside of VS.)

If my current design (UserControl w/states) makes things harder than it needs to be, I'm open to alternative suggestions.  (This is not a webpage, just a regular application with some minor screen navigation + sub-screen navigation within major screens.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an enum (that exposes these three values) property on your UserControl, and use xaml triggers to modify the view (look example bellow).
In order to change state according to menu state, you could address all the menuitems click event to one handler (or to one command) passing the appropriate enum as command parameter or with the Tag property, then set current CurrentState property.
Another way is using a StoryBoard to circle around the states.

Example (replace Window with UserControl, sorry):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public CurrentState CurrentState
  {
    get { return (CurrentState)GetValue(CurrentStateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(CurrentStateProperty, value); }
  }
  public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentStateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("CurrentState", typeof(CurrentState),
      typeof(MainWindow), new UIPropertyMetadata(CurrentState.MainMenu));    
}

public enum CurrentState
{
  MainMenu,
  Config1,
  Config2
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window 
  x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1">
  <Window.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type src:MainWindow}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="CurrentState" Value="MainMenu">
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Window.Style>
</Window>
```